# Get value from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following JSON response received from server:

```
   {
    "msg": "S",
    "comments": {
        "iRecords": [{
            "id": "9",
            "bid": "1",
            "uid": "5",
            "comment": "This is # 009",
            "adate": "Tuesday, 5th April, 2011 11:15:05",
            "status": "1",
            "userid": "5",
            "username": "pavlos",
            "oauthprovider": "l",
            "profile_link": null
        }]
    }
  }
```

Iam using following javascript/jQuery to get values but it is showing nothing:

```
obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
alert(obj.comments.iRecords[adate]);
```

Note: `alert(obj.msg);`  is working fine.

How can I get value of adate in Javascript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "iRecords":[{ <--- iRecords is an array of objects so i think it should be like this: alert(obj.comments.iRecords[0].adate);

Comment: per others, you want obj.comments.iRecords[0].adate;   You should consider using a developer plugin with your browser, or a javascript console, to easily test / debug such issues. The Firebug plugin for Firefox is one popular example, and you can harness the power of jQuery (or whatever library your page includes) through it.

Answer (score 5):

`iRecords` holds an array of objects, so you need to access the first index of the array to get to the first object:

```
obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText); 
alert(obj.comments.iRecords[0]["adate"]);
```

or

```
alert(obj.comments.iRecords[0].adate);
```

Answer (score 5):

You haven't defined a variable called `adate` and `iRecords` is an array

If you use square bracket notation then you have to pass in a string containing the property name, not a variable with the same name as the property.

```
obj.comments.iRecords[0].adate;
```

Answer (score 1):

obj has a comments object which has an iRecods member which is an array with 1 element so;

```
x = obj.comments.iRecords[0].adate
```